# Multiple RecyclerView nesting

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to implement a multi-level comment page. Now, I am using two RecyclerView nests, which is the parent RecyclerView's Item contains another child RecyclerView. The RecyclerView has an expand or collapse feature to display more comments. I feel that this implementation is not very good, I would like to ask if there is a better way to achieve it. Thanks...

as follow:

[image]

The parent RecyclerView's item layout is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="subtitle" />

        <!--child recyclerView-->
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view_sub"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
            android:visibility="gone" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Look at this: [link](https://android.jlelse.eu/get-expandable-recyclerview-in-a-simple-way-8946046b4573}

Comment: Only thing you need is single recyclerview. You need to use more than one item types and more viewholders for this.

Comment: @SebastianPakieła In the sub comment, there is a function of expanding and retracting. If use multiple item types , for example, to expand the 10th to 20th, there seems to be no corresponding method to implement this.

Comment: @Ferran Thanks, I dynamically add a view to the LinearLayout, it is ok！！！as follow:  https://user-gold-cdn.xitu.io/2019/4/11/16a0c3002d99abd9?w=464&h=960&f=gif&s=463056

Comment: Looks great! :)

Answer (score 0):

Sure, You can use ExpandableListView instead of using inherited recycler view.

[Follow the official document](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView)